# Using SMO to script table as select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scripting, smo

SSMS allows you to right-click a table and "Script Table as"->"Select to". I thought that almost everything in SSMS was done through the SMO scripting engine, but I can't seem to find a way to do this through SMO short of looping through columns and generating the script myself.

Is my Google-Fu weak, or are people just not using SMO for something like this? I couldn't find any example scripts for this anywhere, but it seems like it would be a common need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Script()` function of a table can do that:

```
Server server = new Server(".");
Database northwind = server.Databases["Northwind"];
Table categories = northwind.Tables["Categories"];
StringCollection script = categories.Script();
string[] scriptArray = new string[script.Count];
script.CopyTo(scriptArray, 0);
```

Now `scriptArray` will contain a list of SQL commands, the first entry of the string array will be `set ansi_nulls on`.  See this [blog post](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/09/2795.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but that generates a creation script. I'm looking for a select script

Comment: Can't find a way to generate a select script.  But that should be easy to implement?